# ¿Se pueden comparar condicionales en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

¿Se puede hacer comparaciones entre `IF` e `IFNULL`?

Me refiero a que quiero comparar una sentencia IFNULL con otras IFNULL y tomar el reslutado mayor de entre ellas, pero no se como realizarlo o si se puede hacer.

A su vez tengo una duda con la sentencia `GROUP BY` la estoy usando para no mostrar resultados repetidos, pero al usarla(me pasa con algunas items que deseo buscar) la busqueda se lleva incluso 4 minutos; uso `EXPLAIN` para mostrar los tipos y me sale que hay unas que son `ALL` y quiero ver si se puede optimizar de alguna manera para que no me consulte todos los registros.

Comment: Por supuesto que se pueden comparar y tienes muchas alternativas, desde `CASE WHEN ... END` hasta `GREATEST()` . Para que te podamos ayudar, pega la estructura de tablas, datos, sentencias SQL y el resultado del `EXPLAIN` que estés ejecutando

Comment: En cuando al GROUP BY, puedes usar DISTINCT en su lugar.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, el GREATEST me fucnionó a la perfección; solamente que el problema del EXPLAIN no, ese me sigue arrojando el type: ALL y es que el problema es que no hay relación en las tablas que uso y necesito reducir el tiempo de busqueda, ya use FORCE INDEX() y USE INDEX() pero no se soluciona.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar a saber como reducir el tiempo?...saludos

Comment: pon tu consulta y la estructura de las tablas para ver si se puede hacer algo